# Win10: Unable to use left mouse button for clicking in popups

Tags: windows-10, mouse, popups, mouse-buttons

I have a very strange error with the PC in my family. Here are the symptoms:

The system can be used just fine - opening programs, clicking on the windows button, ... Response times are as expected.

However, each time a popup from a local program opens (for example: when you exit a program and it wants to ask "are you sure to exit this program?") I do see the buttons within the popup, but I am unable to **click** on them. Means: I can move the mouse cursor over it, but when clicking the left mouse button, simply nothing happens. I can try to do so many times, but no effect. The only thing which still works with the popup is the **X** button (to close the popup) to top right corner (clicking to the "abort" or "no" button does not work either)

To cross check, I already changed my mouse, switched to another program via keyboard + using the mouse buttons afterwards, used the mouse (going to the task bar below) and switching the program there - always works just fine.

After a while, I figured out, that I am able to change the modal button of the popup by using the TAB key on the keyboard. I can also execute any operation from the popup then by using the "space" bar, which has the same effect as clicking.

The same effect also holds true, if I logon via a remote control tool (such as UltraVNC) from another client to this PC (then serving as host): There also navigating and triggering via keyboard works, but the mouse click command in that special case also is ignored. So, I think this rules out any physical/hardware-related root cause.

My current guess somewhere goes into the direction of the OS and/or the drivers. But where to start?

Environment:

- Windows 10 Pro x64
- Asus Motherboard
- Geforce 210
- 1 TB HDD, Western Digital
- plus the usual stuff (keyboard, mouse, DVD reader)

Does anyone have a hint how to approach this kind of problem?

Comment: Hope this helps to clarify the question. When you use the Tab and Space or Enter combination, does the click work?

Comment: @Epoxy: I am unable to check that in the meantime (see also my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, when trying to reproduce the issue (via remote control tooling) this morning, the issue disappeared. There was no indication to me, how I fixed it. I checked the Windows Update history, but also there is no indication to it (last change from 2016-05-24).

Let's hope that it does not reappear again.